# How to set per-user quota limit in dovecot?

Tags: email, dovecot

I have set-up mail server which uses dovecot as LDA and IMAP/POP3 & MUA is roundcube. I have to authenticate using LDAP. I want to implement per-user quota, but I cannot use any field in existing LDAP nor can I add new. Can I use any other backends for quota purpose only. I have tried using dict-sql backend after following instructions in: "https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/quota/quota_dict/" but instead of quota getting limited current quota (occupied) appears in quota table. What I am doing wrong or what have I misunderstood?